# DeX: file copy?

Tags: samsung-dex

I came across with a very interesting problem:

Given a Samsung phone (Fold3), and an USB docking station, and 2 thumb drives.

I wanted to copy files (10Gb total) from Thumb1 to Thumb2 with the phone (FX commander).

No matter what I tried, 10 of 10 attempts failed with various reasons (USB became instable, please reset phone, etc etc etc). Sometimes the whole UI was frozen for a couple of minutes.

Then I realized that using all the same equipment, but also plugging a monitor to the dock solves the file copy issue.

If I do this on DeX, 10 of 10 times success.

What could I do to make this work without DeX?

Comment: Was the USB docking station an active or a passive powered one? Fast USB sticks can draw a lot power so if the hub is passive the power usage may be the problem.

Comment: Its a powered one. Actually I found out if I use a full featured typec typec cable between dock and phone, large file transfer corrupts the thumbdrive during write phase. However if I use a nonfull-featured cable (charging cable ie), it works perfectly, just a little bit slower.

Comment: That would men the USB3 supports somehow causes the problem. The simple cable most likely only supports USB2 and that works reliable.